# Cannot establish connection to application listening on 0.0.0.0:8443

Tags: connection, netstat

I have an application that is listening on 0.0.0.0:8443 (local address). 
"netstat -ant" output: 
proto||Recv-Q||Send-Q||Local Address||Foreign Address||State
tcp||0||0||0.0.0.0:22||0.0.0.0:*||LISTEN 

tcp||0||0||0.0.0.0:8443||0.0.0.0:*||LISTEN

These are the only two ports that are listening.  When i telnet localhost port 22 and 8443, both are able to connect. But when i telnet from another computer on the same subnet, i am able to connect to port 22 but not port 8443.  The host and client computer are only connected via a switch.  What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not open in IPtables. Please follow the below link for same.

https://serverfault.com/questions/301903/cannot-access-port-80-from-remote-location-but-works-on-local

guess it deals with same question.

Comment: Thanks Aravind.  The issue was related to firewall on CentOS 7.  There is a firewall-cmd that can be used to expose ports to external hosts (besides localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the firewall settings? Maybe you need to open tcp port from iptables?